# Finding values between two values over a specific amount of time

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, range

let's say I have two values: 600 & 470

What I'm trying to do is specify a set of time, let's say 0 and 100 (4 seconds if 25fps) and then get the 'tween' values for each 'frame'.

```
var base = 600;
var target = 470;
var start = 0;
var end = 100;
var values = [];
for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
    // not sure where to begin with the math here
    // so i'll just asssign it to i, but obviously it's wrong
    var value = i;
    values.push(value);

}
// Once complete, id expect:
// values[0] === 600;
// values[99] === 470;
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the increment (between each item in the array), and then you can create the array all at once by mapping each `i` to `base + increment * i`:

```js
const base = 600;
const target = 470;
const start = 0;
const end = 100;
const increment = (target - base) / (end - start - 1);
const values = Array.from(
  { length: end - start },
  (_, i) => base + increment * i
);
console.log(values[0]);
console.log(values[99]);
console.log(values);
```

Comment: This is amazingly elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I made an easy solution to this question.

Two variable added:

1. difference
2. rate

The base value minus rated differences to get step values.

```js
var base = 600;
var target = 470;
var start = 0;
var end = 100;
var values = [];

var difference = base-target;
for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
    var rate = (i/(end-1));
    var value = base - (difference*rate);
    values.push(value);
}
// Once complete, id expect:
// values[0] === 600;
// values[99] === 470;
console.log(values);
```